# FabricJS clippath border color and move the overlay image behind clippath?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs, fabricjs2

I am trying to add the clippath area(rect object) over canvas using fabricJS. Currently i set Overlay Image to the canvas and in addition to that am adding clippath area to place objects. I successfully able to place the object inside the clippath, but the problem is whatever image i place it inside clippath has opacity(means object also has transparency), i know is because i set transparent image as overlay which is always top over other object.

My query is

1. Can i set the clippath area alone to ignore overlay? Or atleast to set the preference like clippath is first priority and next overlay?
2. Currently clippath has no border and i couldn't know where the clippath is? So is there a way to set the border over clippath area?

Here is my below code

HTML

```
<canvas id="ex8" width="300" height="400"></canvas>
```

JS

```js
(function () {
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('ex8');
  canvas.controlsAboveOverlay = true;
  var clipPath = new fabric.Rect({ width: 100, height: 100, fill: 'red', top: 100, left: 100 });

  canvas.setOverlayImage(
    'https://i.ibb.co/88QkSMC/crew-front.png',
    canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
    {}
  );
  var group = new fabric.Group([
    new fabric.Rect({ width: 100, height: 100, fill: 'red', globalCompositeOperation: 'xor' }),

    new fabric.Rect({ width: 100, height: 100, fill: 'blue', top: 100 }),
    new fabric.Rect({ width: 100, height: 100, fill: 'green', left: 100, top: 100 }),
  ]);

  canvas.clipPath = clipPath;
  canvas.add(group);
})();
```

Appreciate your help !!!

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vignesh_pichamani/p3m46ad0/81/)**

Comment: You have multiple questions from what I can see at least 4, can you narrow this to just one?

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting question.

The issue you encounter is linked to the order in which layers are being applied in `Fabric.js`.

As described in a related [github](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/wiki/How-fabric-canvas-layering-works) post, the layers are applied as follows (from bottom up):

[image: The order of various physical and functional "layers" of canvas]

Hence, it's not that the `clipPath` is put on the T-shirt image (i.e. the `Overlay image`). It's the opposite, as the T-shirt layer is applied over the clipPath.

While it seems that the "transparency" comes from the `clipPath` resp. `fabric group`, it is actually coming from the `Overlay image` itself as the T-shirt in the image is transparent (the surrounding white background is not).

The opacity of the T-shirt image is also visible when hovering over it with a mouse (e.g. in file explorer as depicted below).

[image: T-shirt image on white and light blue background.]

As for the borders, you can add the following to your code:

```
group.set({
    borderColor: 'yellow',
    cornerColor: 'yellow',
    cornerSize: 6,
    transparentCorners: false
  });
group.setActiveObject(canvas);
```

Please note that the borders are only visible when the corresponding canvas item is activated. For more information, you can check this [link](http://fabricjs.com/customization) on customization.

Comment: @colorCoder Where is Link?